# Eclipse Package Declaration Work Around?

Tags: eclipse, package, declaration

The team in which I'm working doesn't use eclipse and wants the src folder to be setup a certain way.  I, on the other hand, am using eclipse.  They would like the src folder to have, for example, the following structure: src/main/java/com/*  However, they would like package declarations to only have com.* in them.  If I go to project->properties and in the source tab remove the src folder as a source folder and then _only add the com.* folder as part of the source_ it will show com.* as a package, but I still have to add the whole path from src down in the .java files.  Here's an example of what I have to do in order for eclipse to recognize the packages:

```
package main.java.com.parser;
```

And what the team wants is to have *main* and *java* just be a folder so the package declaration would just be:

```
package com.parser;
```

So although the file structure would still be src/main/java/com/parser, the package name would be as stated in the later example.

Is there a way to do this in eclipse?  **I've seen some people asking similar questions on here, but they seem to have no concern that the whole path must be part of the package declaration.**

I would much prefer not to do this this way, but no one else is using eclipse on this project.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Package Explorer, right click the `src` folder and select Build Path > Remove from Build Path

Then find the src/main/java folder, right click `java` and select Build Path > Use as Source Folder

Basically this tell eclipse that `java` is the folder which contains the packages and source files.

P.S. This is a very normal project setup for building with Maven. If you download the m2e (Maven to Eclipse) plugins and choose to create a Maven Project (or import from the pom.xml) then Eclipse will automatically know how to correctly locate the source folder.

Comment: Ugh...  Apparently eclipse wasn't updating the package name...  Once I closed the file and reopened it, the error went away.  Thank you for this.  So this is a duplicate question, sorry.  Thank you very much for confirming this though.

Comment: Sure thing. I really recommend you checkout the `m2e` plugin as it sounds like your coworkers are using Maven to build with. If this is the case, then `m2e` will save you a lot of pain by providing easy ways to keep your eclipse project in sync with the development project. Basically, `m2e` can facilitate updating eclipse's build path based on the `pom.xml`

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Yes, we are using maven and they have a pom.xml that they say makes our lives easier, but I'm still trying to get on board with my local build and exlipse.  I will absolutely look into the m2e plugin.  I'm a big fan of making things easier. :)

Comment: Maven, you'll love it, you'll hate it, but it is marginally better than the next best thing, making it the best out there.